Error using BoundedVec for Pallet Storage, says many traits are not implemented for `BoundedVec<snip>`
Here's a snip from my file showing the relevant stuff:
#[pallet::config]
pub trait Config: frame_system::Config {
    /// The ID type for freezes.
    type FreezeIdentifier: Parameter + Member + MaxEncodedLen + Copy;
    /// The maximum number of individual freeze locks that can exist on an account at any 
    time.
    #[pallet::constant]
    type MaxFreezes: Get<u32>;
}
#[pallet::storage]
pub type Freezes<T: Config> = StorageMap<
    _,
    Blake2_128Concat,
    T::AccountId,
    BoundedVec<IdAmount<T::FreezeIdentifier, T::NativeBalance>, T::MaxFreezes>,
    ValueQuery,
>;

It's giving me a ton of errors all with the same format, just for different traits such as Encode and Decode:
error[E0277]: the trait bound `BoundedVec<IdAmount<<T as pallet::Config>::FreezeIdentifier, <T as pallet::Config>::NativeBalance>, <T as pallet::Config>::MaxFreezes>: parity_scale_codec::Decode` is not satisfied
   --> pallets/bullposting/src/lib.rs:48:15
    |
48  |       #[pallet::pallet]
    |  _______________^
49  | |     pub struct Pallet<T>(_);
50  | |
51  | |     /// The pallet's configuration trait.
...   |
133 | |     #[pallet::storage]
134 | |     pub type Freezes<T: Config> = StorageMap<
    | |____________________^ the trait `parity_scale_codec::Decode` is not implemented for `BoundedVec<IdAmount<<T as pallet::Config>::FreezeIdentifier, <T as pallet::Config>::NativeBalance>, <T as pallet::Config>::MaxFreezes>`, which is required by `frame_support::pallet_prelude::StorageMap<_GeneratedPrefixForStorageFreezes<T>, frame_support::Blake2_128Concat, <T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId, BoundedVec<IdAmount<<T as pallet::Config>::FreezeIdentifier, <T as pallet::Config>::NativeBalance>, <T as pallet::Config>::MaxFreezes>, frame_support::pallet_prelude::ValueQuery>: StorageInfoTrait`
    |
    = note: required for `BoundedVec<IdAmount<<T as pallet::Config>::FreezeIdentifier, <T as pallet::Config>::NativeBalance>, <T as pallet::Config>::MaxFreezes>` to implement `FullCodec`
    = note: required for `StorageMap<_GeneratedPrefixForStorageFreezes<T>, Blake2_128Concat, <T as Config>::AccountId, BoundedVec<..., ...>, ...>` to implement `StorageInfoTrait`
    = note: the full name for the type has been written to '/home/tgang/rust/BullChain/target/debug/deps/pallet_bullposting-a4d011cb0bb97c3a.long-type-9057226278347970660.txt'
    = note: consider using `--verbose` to print the full type name to the console
help: consider introducing a `where` clause, but there might be an alternative better way to express this requirement
    |
48  |     #[pallet::pallet where BoundedVec<IdAmount<<T as pallet::Config>::FreezeIdentifier, <T as pallet::Config>::NativeBalance>, <T as pallet::Config>::MaxFreezes>: parity_scale_codec::Decode]
    |                      ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

I've found a few other questions along these lines but the fix for both was using Get<u32> instead of Get<u16>, but I'm already using Get<u32>. I copied my code from the Balances pallet.


but the fix for both was using Get<u32> instead of Get<u16>, but I'm already using Get<u32>.

I didn't get your mean.

type MaxFreezes: Get<u32>;
Both of the related Q&As I found had Get<u16> and the solution to their problems was to change it to Get<u32> but I already have that, so neither of those helped me. @AurevoirXavier

Can you share your pallet code? Then I can try to compile it. Since I checked the code that you provided, it's exactly the same as what pallet-balances did.

@AurevoirXavier https://github.com/Yung-Beef/BullChain/tree/master/pallets/bullposting

These default-features should be false.
https://github.com/Yung-Beef/BullChain/blob/8f3ad89d3daa6901c380a96af284bd4dea67e083/pallets/bullposting/Cargo.toml#L25-L26
Those features should only be enabled in std.
Add sp-io/std, pallet-balances/std to the std feature scope.

I just noticed that you are using different versions of dependencies.
You should ensure all dependencies are on the same version.
For example, pallet-balances depends on codec@1.0, while frame-support depends on codec@2.0. The macro from frame-support will assume that you haven't implemented those traits.
You can also check https://github.com/paritytech/psvm.

I did and I still get the errors. https://github.com/Yung-Beef/BullChain/commit/a786c7b789794eacf5dc0f51544244f2a87d48c7
Thanks for the help @AurevoirXavier

Updated my answer.

I ran that with -v polkadot-stable2409-2 (the latest) and it only updated sc-network from 0.45.0 to 0.45.1, with the errors still happening. Does codec@1.0 refer to SCALE? Does pallet-balances need to get updated?

codec is merely an example. I apologize, but I lack the time to verify all your dependencies. However, I’m certain that this issue arises from the inconsistent version of your dependencies. In my opinion, managing git dependencies is easier compared to crates. Personally, I won't use crates dependencies.

https://github.com/polkadot-evm/frontier/blob/18aa99b365d32a1524b4e7591f3797378c11fb0f/Cargo.toml#L85-L160, this is the recommended way to manage dependencies. You can simply keep all dependencies at same the commit.

Okay, I'll try updating everything to be like that and see. Thanks for your time!
